# How do you know if a weapon is two-handed in D&D2E?

Tags: adnd-2e

In second edition AD&D,

The only weapons I can find that are explicitly stated to be two-handed weapons are a *two-handed sword* and a *(two handed) bastard sword*, which can also be used one-handed.

But every other weapon that I can see doesn't specify.

What about a Battle Axe or a War hammer?  They sound like they could be used two-handed.  And if not, are there no other two-handed weapons in existence?

[image: weapon chart 1]
[image: weapon chart 2]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Handedness is based on the size of the weapon compared to the size of the character. Same size and smaller requires 1 hand, one size larger requires 2 and 2 sizes larger cannot be wielded.

If it's large and you are size medium then the weapon requires two hands.

Answer (score 20):

Chapter 6 on Weapons on Weapon Size says that

> A character can always wield a weapon equal to his own size or less. Normally this requires only one hand, except for some missile weapons.... A character can also use a weapon one size greater than himself, although it must be gripped with two hands. (*Player's Handbook* (1995) 96)

Thus, for example, a Medium creature using a trident must use that trident in two hands.